# How to spy on jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I want my tool to be able to spy on jQuery events(only jQuery is enough as all my projects uses it to bind events).

I am not testing but writing tool which works based on triggered events.

What I have found which suits my needs is [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#event-spies) which is really nice and awesome but I do not want to include Jasmine or to use it. I would like it to be standalone or simple jQuery plugin.

I would appreciate any input or direction.

**What more have I tried?**

I thought about writing my own `jQuery` plugin for it which would let me do things like:

```
var clicked = Events.click.haveBeenTriggeredOn('#some_element');
var scrolled = Events.scroll.toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#other_element')
```

**Even better yet** - support callbacks. Now anyone can say - what's wrong with attaching one more handler to the element manually like:

```
$(selector).on('click', function() { yourBeautifulCallback() });
```

And what can I say - nothing. Except it's not elegant and requires manual labor all over the place and I **fear of breaking things up** in existing app.

Comment: just write a quick proxy function that accepts arguments for $.on(), logging the subscription and ultimately binding to $.on()...

Comment: @dandavis this is really nice. However the codebase is over 6 years old and there are still parts using live(), bind() and on(). I want to minimize collisions and modification of codebase. 3 proxy functions.. well this is my approach if I will not receive a solution :)

Comment: [.live()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.live), [.bind()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.bind) - they both use `.on()` so it would only be one proxy function